# Connection CLOUD-SQL to Google-Data-Studio, what is wrong?

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, looker-studio

I'm trying to establish a connection between Cloud SQL and Data Studio. I've already tried to make a connection through the MySQL connector with a MySQL db and it failed because I think the Router did not allow the connection.

Then I transferred the db on the cloud but I have the same error!!! Which is:
***ID errore: f73c5f49***

I already opened Cloud-SQL to all the Data Studio IP addresses, I've created users with "%" and given them all the privileges, I created instance, db and user in CLOUD-SQL (MySQL, 2nd generation).

What else can I try? Could it still be a Router problem?I have to do that for work but it keeps saying that connector parameters are wrong.

PLEASE HELP <3 THANKS A LOT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common error is to write the instance name instead of the "instance connection name".

You can find the "Instance Connection Name" in the instance page, in the overview section, and normally the format is something like:

> [PROJECT_ID]:[region]:[NAME_SQL_INSTANCE]

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar connection problem with MySql 8.0 but changing to 5.7 fixed it.